# Get customized element from `vcard` using `xmpp` and `smack`

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I created a `vcard` with custom elements:

```
<vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'><NICKNAME>nickname</NICKNAME><elementName xmlns='xmlns:custom'><avatar>elementName_avatar_3.png</avatar></elementName></vCard>
```

when however I ask this `vcard`, my result is:

```
<iq xmlns='jabber:client' to='602157@peropenfire101.per.local/3r6td85ng7' from='271087@peropenfire101.per.local' id='jA5pI-33' type='result'><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'><JABBERID>271087@peropenfire101.per.local/4usgw7j7u</JABBERID><NICKNAME>nickname</NICKNAME></vCard></iq>
```

as you can see, the custom elements are missing.
this is my request:

```
try {
        connection.sendStanzaWithResponseCallback(
                new cdcd(from),
                new StanzaFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(Stanza stanza) {
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                new StanzaListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void processStanza(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException, InterruptedException, SmackException.NotLoggedInException {
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

private class cdcd extends Stanza{

    private final Jid from;

    public cdcd(Jid from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence toXML(String enclosingNamespace) {
        return "<iq from=\'"+ from +"\' id='v1' type='get'><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/></iq>";
    }
}
```

I don't know how fix this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [XEP-054](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html) the feature of non-standard elements of vCard DTD is not supported, so your XMPP server ignore them.

> Unfortunately, Dawson's proposal did not move forward within the IETF's standards process. For reasons now lost in the mists of time, the Jabber project continued to use the DTD from draft-dawson-vcard-xml-dtd-01, making two small modifications to adapt it for use within the Jabber community (adding the JABBERID and DESC elements) but also specifying element names in all caps rather than lowercase as defined in draft-dawson-vcard-xml-dtd-01. In addition, the Jabber community followed the usage (but not DTD) in that draft regarding version information, including it as an attribute of the vCard element rather than as a child element. This format was implemented within the Jabber community under the 'vcard-temp' namespace.

You can see [here](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html#dtd) the all supported elements.
Also see the discussion [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2927)

Comment: @thorny84 , I would be very happy to know how exactly you solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved...
I created a new class that extends `VCardProvider`, and I parsed my custom tag in the overridden method parse

```
public class CustomVCardProvider extends VCardProvider {

private static final String[] TEL = new String[]{
        "VOICE",
        "FAX",
        "PAGER",
        "MSG",
        "CELL",
        "VIDEO",
        "BBS",
        "MODEM",
        "ISDN",
        "PCS",
        "PREF",
};

private static final String[] ADR = new String[]{
        "POSTAL",
        "PARCEL",
        "DOM",
        "INTL",
        "PREF",
        "POBOX",
        "EXTADR",
        "STREET",
        "LOCALITY",
        "REGION",
        "PCODE",
        "CTRY",
        "FF",
};

@Override
public VCard parse(XmlPullParser parser, int initialDepth) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

    VCard vCard = new VCard();
    String name = null;

    outerloop:
    while (true) {
        int eventType = parser.next();
        switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                switch (name) {
                    case CUSTOM_TAG:
                        parseCustomTag(parser, vCard);
                        break;
                    case "N":
                        parseName(parser, vCard);
                        break;
                    case "ORG":
                        parseOrg(parser, vCard);
                        break;
                    case "TEL":
                        parseTel(parser, vCard);
                        break;
                    case "ADR":
                        parseAddress(parser, vCard);
                        break;
                    case "EMAIL":
                        parseEmail(parser, vCard);
                        break;
                    case "NICKNAME":
                        vCard.setNickName(parser.nextText());
                        break;
                    case "JABBERID":
                        vCard.setJabberId(parser.nextText());
                        break;
                    case "PHOTO":
                        parsePhoto(parser, vCard);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                if (initialDepth + 1 == parser.getDepth()) {
                    vCard.setField(name, parser.getText());
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                if (parser.getDepth() == initialDepth) {
                    break outerloop;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return vCard;
}
```

Don't forget to copy all parsers from the original provider and add `ProviderManager.addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new CustomVCardProvider());` after authentication